# AWS: Is it good practice to use api gateway to proxy both frontend and backend api endpoints served in EC2 instances?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

I am building my app in AWS.

I have deployed my Reactjs frontend project in an EC2 instance: `172.0.0.1:80`.

I have also deployed my Typescript/Express JS backend service running many api endpoints in another EC2 instance: `172.0.0.2:3000`.

`172.0.0.1` and `172.0.0.2` are the EC2 instances' VPC private IP addresses.

I am trying to use AWS API Gateway for reverse proxy purpose, but I'm not sure if this is a good practice, or a good way to use AWS cloud tools in general. The details are:

- I have configured my custom domain to the api gateway, so that any visits to `www.myapp.com` are directed to the api gateway.
- If a user enters url `www.myapp.com` in his browser, API Gateway would proxy the http GET request to `172.0.0.1:80`
- As the user is interacting with the frontend, GET/PUT/POST requests are triggered and the destination urls all have patterns like `www.myapp.com/api/[xxx]`. e.g.
  `www.myapp.com/api/user`, `www.myapp.com/api/photos`, ....

  API Gateway would proxy these request to `172.0.0.2:3000`.
- I also want to integrate AWS Cognito service with the API gateway for Authentication purpose, so that users can sign in / sign out.

Now, is this a good practice to use api gateway in such a way?

Is this a proper way to host an app on AWS cloud?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This seems like a reasonable approach.  This is a bit of an opinionated question because "good practice and "proper way" are subjective.  API Gateway is flexible and allows many usage patterns that could be "good practice" and could be done in a "proper way" and yet still be quite different.

That said, the approach seems reasonable, but you may be able to host the frontend project differently to be more efficient.  Consider the approach shown in [Building server-side rendering for React in AWS Lambda](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-server-side-rendering-for-react-in-aws-lambda/):
[image: Image from https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/compute/building-server-side-rendering-for-react-in-aws-lambda/]

In that approach the frontend is static and rendered on the client, so using S3 to store the static files and using CloudFront to distribute those is a good approach. It shows a dynamic backend beind processed by Lambda, which has serverless advantages, but it could be EC2 just as well. If you have frontend code that is not static or that you otherwise want to come from an EC2 instance, you could do that instead and use API Gateway as you outlined.

One thing I like about your approach compared to this picture is that the client has a single domain for the app, and API Gateway does the routing to the correct endpoint.  That keep some implementation details hidden from end users.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. A good challenge I am trying to overcome now (as a newbie) is to integrate AWS Cognito in the flow., such that when user first visits, he is directed to the sign-in page of AWS Cognito automatically.

Comment: Although this definitely works, it requires the API and the Web domain to be different. You can't use www.myapp.com/api for the API and www.myapp.com/ for web. You need two different domains: api.myapp.com, web.myapp.com and properly configure CORS.

Comment: @Shawn  I don't think this would work, once we add Authorization to the flow: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70449251/aws-how-can-i-use-aws-cognito-to-provide-authorization-service-for-a-webapp-hos  Cloudfront simply does not provide an integration with AWS Cognito or other Oauth service.

Comment: @kgiannakakis I can integrate AWS Cognito with AWS API Gateway, but not with Cloudfront.