# AWS S3 bucket with React app: it is possible with my React SPA that is partially static?

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, frontend, amazon-cloudfront

I want to host my React frontend with AWS CloudFront with S3 bucket.

Currently, my app is deployed in an EC2 instance and here is the outline:

Frontend: React app running on port `80`. When a user goes to `https://myapp.com`, the request is directed to `my-ec2-instance:80`.

Backend: Express JS running on port `3000`. When the user loads the frontend in the browser and when he interacts with the website, http requests are sent to `https://myapp.com/api/*`, which are routed to `my-ec2-instance:3000`;

I want to take the frontend out of the ec2 instance and host with AWS CloudFront with S3 bucket, such that the EC2 instance only host the backend service.

I have read that AWS CloudFront / S3 bucket can only host static websites.

In this case, is my React frontend a static Single Page Application, or is it dynamic?

Can I do it?

Comment: See [Deploy a React-based single-page application to Amazon S3 and CloudFront](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/prescriptive-guidance/latest/patterns/deploy-a-react-based-single-page-application-to-amazon-s3-and-cloudfront.html) for some guidance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your application is dynamic, since you need Express. S3 can only serve static content and can't be used for hosting node.js applications. You can still serve your static content from S3 and host Express in an EC2 instance, but your deployment strategy will be more complicated.

If you host both static and dynamic content in the EC2 instance, then in CloudFront you need path based routing, which is nicely explained [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54446347/path-based-routing-to-cloudfront-and-ec2).

Comment: Thank you for the guide!!  By the way, this was the plan I've had in mind for weeks: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70352817/aws-is-it-good-practice-to-use-api-gateway-to-proxy-both-frontend-and-backend-a   I think you have a great perspective and your answer exactly addresses this post as well. Would you mind taking a look and maybe comment as well? It describes my intentions better.  I haven't accepted any answers for that post yet. Your answer should be accepted.

Comment: After trying Cloudfront out, I started to think it cannot do authorization with an Oauth server like AWS cognito. I've read many blogs/docs, and I figured that Cloudfront is not build for the purpose: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70449251/aws-how-can-i-use-aws-cognito-to-provide-authorization-service-for-a-webapp-hos   Would you mind also take a look?

Comment: Many examples out there to integrate Cognito with a React App. Start from https://medium.com/@corymaklin/aws-part-7-user-sign-up-sign-in-and-access-control-using-amplify-cognito-and-react-c484ed8bb44