# AWS API Gateway: 403 MissingAuthenticationTokenException for /static/js/bundle.js even though Authorization is set as None

Tags: reactjs, amazon-web-services, web, frontend

I have set up this flow:

external world --> AWS API Gateway ---> VPC Link ---> Network Load Balancer ---> my single EC2 instance

The API Gateway is working because when I input the custom domain in my browser, it successfully visits the frontend service running on my EC2 instance.

However, for `/static/js/bundle.js`, I'm getting a 403 `MissingAuthenticationTokenException` error:

[image]

But the request to the main domain is ok:

[image]

Also, all other resources failed:
`/static/js/vendors~main.chunk.js`

`static/js/main.chunk.js`

`/favicon.ico`

`/manifest.json`

My frontend is written in React JS.

Note that it says: `x-amzn-errortype: MissingAuthenticationTokenException`.
But I have set the Authorization to be None:

[image]

What is going on?

Comment: Your setup is very strange. API Gateway isn't meant to be used for serving web applications and static content. Among other, there is a size limit for the API Gateway responses. Why not use CloudFront? If your React App is static, you also don't need EC2 and can use S3 web hosting.

Comment: @kgiannakakis I'm not sure if my website is static. Here is a detailed description of my frontend: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70393974/aws-s3-bucket-with-react-app-it-is-possible-with-my-react-spa-that-is-partially   Is CloudFront a good choice in this case? Could you help ?

Comment: It is not static, since you have express. CloudFront is a good choice, you should properly configure to route the web requests to port 80 and API requests to port 3000.

Comment: @kgiannakakis I was trying to configure to route requests to port 80 and API requests to port 3000 with API Gateway. I thought Cloudfront is built for serving static page (like images/texts/etc). I didn't know you can use Cloudfront to route requests as well.

Comment: @kgiannakakis Sorry if this is a silly question: But Express is the backend, not the frontend, right?  The frontend is basically a Single Page App. Could it still be static? Why using Nodejs / Express for the backend makes it non-static?

Comment: If you are using Express to implement a REST API then it is the back up and the web app is static. However Express could also be used for Server Side Rendering and that would make the web app not static. Read more in https://graphcms.com/blog/difference-spa-ssg-ssr

Comment: @kgiannakakis Awesome thanks for clarifying!  That's exactly it: I am using Typescript/Express and built a REST API. The frontend is a React SPA and components are rendered on the client side based on the data loaded from the Express REST API.   Now, it is becoming clear that I should use Cloudfront + S3 to host the React SPA frontend (with cognito integrated in it); and AWS API Gateway + Cognito in front of the backend (with CORS configured). In this way, I can completely replace nginx/openresty in my original workflow.  Does this sounds good? Any potential issues?

Comment: This is pretty standard, you shouldn't have any problems.